# Use OS X certificate to sign Windows applications

Tags: windows, digital-signature

We are developing cross-platform applications. Our OS X applications are signed and now we want to sign our Windows applications, too. Do we have to request another certificate for that or can we reuse the one we use for signing the OS X applications?

Comment: Both apple and Microsoft use *standard* formats for certificates, you can (re)use same certificate in many platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, it is possible to sign Windows applications with the OS X certificate.

No, because Windows does not know about this Apple certificate and hence will reject the signed Windows application.